# does var_dump() shows class properties?

Tags: php, class, var-dump

If I use `var_dump` to some class, say `DateTime`:

```
<?php

$date = new DateTime();

var_dump($date);
```

I got

```
/var/www/php/test/index.php:5:
object(DateTime)[1]
  public 'date' => string '2021-02-16 23:23:10.768097' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Berlin' (length=13)
```

Which I interpret there are 3 public properties. So I try to access them:

```
<?php

$date = new DateTime();

var_dump($date);

//example of accessing public $date; of class DateTime;
echo $date->date;
```

but I got `Undefined property: DateTime::$date in /var/www/php/test/index.php on line 7`

So how should I interpret `var_dump(some class)`?

Comment: What version of PHP are you running? What's your OS? I am running PHP 7.3.24 from command line and `echo $date->date` shows `2021-02-16 22:36:17.973299`

Comment: php 7.4.9.  5.8.0-43-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 5 03:01:28 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var_dump()` shows both public and private properties.

For PHP up to 7.3 `date` was a public property of DateTime.

From PHP 7.4 `date` is a private property, and attempting to access it returns an `Undefined property` message.

See https://3v4l.org/MW498

Note that these properties are not documented in the PHP manual for [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), so anything you do with them might break, without notice.

Comment: so why does var_dump shows it as public if it is private?

Comment: or does var_dump shows older version of DateClass?

Comment: I don't have an answer to that, except to observe that the PHP built-in functions and classes don't always obey the same rules that classes and functions written in PHP obey.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your statement "built-in function does not obey as classes/functions do"? I thought there is one php standard that dictates semantics for both built-ins and the rest (class, function). Or am I wrong?

Comment: PHP started life as a collection of PERL scripts. It's now mostly (entirely?) written in C++, and the transition hasn't always been as disciplined as it might. This is why we have the vast number of functions with sometimes inconsistent naming conventions and parameter lists. (think of the string functions as an example of naming inconsistency). PHP 7 and PHP 8 have gone a long way to cleaning up the act. more...

Comment: ...There is one PHP standard - the PHP manual. If it's in there you can rely on it. If you stumble over some undocumented property or method then its behaviour is not guaranteed, either by the published standards, or in future versions.